# lineno and obeylines

Tags: line-numbering

How can I number the lines (using lineno) of a text while using obeylines such that I don't have to put a `\\` at the end of every line. I've tried:

```
\newenvironment{foo}
{ \begin{linenumbers}[1] \bgroup\obeylines }
{ \egroup \end{linenumbers} }
```

But this results in a number in front of every outputted line but I'd like to have only numbers on front of every input line.

Also how can I turn off the indent for every line inside this environment?

Using verbatim isn't an alternative because then I can't use footnotes and similar stuff inside this environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from spaces in the input that shouldn't be used, your definition works.

Here's how you remove the indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\newenvironment{foo}
 {\begin{linenumbers}[1]%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \bgroup\obeylines}
 {\egroup\end{linenumbers}}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The purpose of `lineno` is to count the number of lines in the output, so it's not really clear what you want to achieve.

Perhaps something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{foo}
 {\par
  \setcounter{foocount}{0}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \everypar{\stepcounter{foocount}\makebox[0pt][r]{\tiny\thefoocount\enspace}}%
  \bgroup\obeylines}
 {\par\egroup}
\newcounter{foocount}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb
cccc
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]